# How to make my blog using multiple languages in Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll for my blog about Ruby [masteruby](https://masteruby.github.io). Blog is written in English and I want to have my blog written in Slovak language too. Is there any choice to have multiple languages without retyping my posts?

Answer (score 7):

There is many way to handle several languages with Jekyll. You'll have to translate every content: posts, menus and dates. To do this, you can read [Multilingual website with Jekyll](http://sylvaindurand.org/making-jekyll-multilingual/) I wrote several months ago. This is just one way to do this: once you start to master Liquid, you'll be able to fit your needs.

However, I don't know what you mean when you say "without retyping my posts". You'll have to translate by yourself the posts you want to be available in both languages.

Comment: Your post looks great. That's exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The provided link is broken, I found the post at: http://sylvaindurand.org/making-jekyll-multilingual/

Comment: Thanks for your vigilance, the redirection broke. I corrected the link.

Answer (score 0):

For those still in need of an easy solution, here is a plugin that I have created that does just that. It creates multiple translations of pages and posts according to its front-matter. You can choose to translate a post into multiple languages or just adopt the original post for another language.

https://github.com/vwochnik/jekyll-language-plugin